# What battery is lightweight and has a lot of power?

Tags: batteries, battery-operated

I'm creating an Arduino project, for that project I'm looking for batteries like the ones used to power scooters or electric wheelchairs, so powerful that they can carry the weight of a human and last for a long time.

I've seen some electric wheelchairs, but the batteries are huge in size and weight. I'm looking for something lighter, that has the same power as an electric wheelchair, and relatively cheap that people like me could buy, the battery has to be rechargeable of course.

maximum potential speed is like 20 km/h maybe less, but the normal speed will be around 5 to 10 km/h, distance around 80 km, i have no problem using some sort of a regenerative brake system or solar power system.

What are my options?

I've been told about Vmax tank and agm batteries, from what I see, it seems too heavy. I need something portable, and don't mind using 2 batteries instead of 1. From what I know, a scooter battery is 12 volts, so I need something like that; or 6 volts and use 2 batteries.

I'm looking for batteries the size of Samsung S4, or an iPad maximum. I know a lot of people who gave me many options but none portable so far.

I'm not going to discuss the project because it's outside this topic, but basically I have 2 problems with my project, finding the right batteries is the first one, I'll discuss the second problem later. Maybe the battery that I'm searching for doesn't exist

I don't care if it's lithium or not.

Comment: Carrying the weight of a human doesn't need a powerful battery and all of them will last for a long time. While I'm in my pedantic mood, how about specifying speed, distance, load, potential for regen braking in your project (or solar maybe).

Comment: Try a long extension cord.

Comment: When you find a battery that is the size of a couple credit cards stacked on each other that has the capability to push a human around for a few hours, let Tesla Motors know.  They'd be interested in the upgrade.

Comment: @OlinLathrop  +1.  The O.P. should also consider [trolley poles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trolley_pole).  Seriously, however, the O.P. should read through http://batteryuniversity.com.

Comment: *"something lighter, that has the same power as an electric wheelchair, and relatively cheap"* - If they exist why don't wheelchair makers use them?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick i don't know if they exist or not, the answer proved that they do exist,  however to answer your question, the cheapest wheelchair you can get in my country is made in china, the gov imports it, it is the cheapest electrical wheelchair you can find in my country and it costs 5000$, so if you use advanced tech on wheelchairs, the disabled won't be able to buy them i guess, it's not worth it for mass production

Comment: @Andyaka "Carrying the weight of a human doesn't need a powerful battery" i wanted to discuss that in my next topic, choosing the right power generator, i mentioned, that im facing 2 problems, the 2nd one is the generator :) maximum potential speed is like 20 km/h maybe less, but the normal speed will be around 5 to 10 km/h, distance around 80 km and i am considering Regenerative brake but havent mention it coz i havent done enough research on it for my project, and yes  solar power is also an option

Comment: @Fischer: I'm confused. You said you were looking for *"I'm looking for something ... relatively cheap that people like me could buy,"*. Are you saying that LiPo batteries are cheap enough for you to buy but not cheap enough for [wheelchair buyers](http://www.wheelchairdriver.com/lithium-batteries-wheelchair-powerchair.htm)?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick i just looked on ebay, lipo costs like 66$ so yes you're right, it's not the price, maybe coz it's dangerous, i mean if the wheelchair hit the wall or something, maybe they dont use it for safety, its just assumptions, you have to ask the manufacturers, i have no idea why they dont use it

Comment: @Fischer I wasn't asking for me, I was asking so you can edit and improve your question should you feel this data is needed of course.

Comment: @Andyaka you're right sir

Comment: Why is this being answered and not being considered a shopping question?

Comment: @mikeY possibly because it's a "what technology" rather than what component question. Borderline though.

Comment: @mikeY Sir i don't care about shopping, and never done shopping in my entire life, as for the question, if it was about shopping then there would be too many batteries to choose from, which is not the case... thats why guys like Olin Lathrop and insta are making fun of me, they believe that what im asking for doesn't even exist... that proves that i'm not doing shopping here, i have a project to be done, i'm asking if the batteries i want exist, and i'll buy whatever is offered to me, and so far there's only 1 answer which proves that it's rare to find what i'm after

Comment: @fischer  You misunderstand.  You and I are of the same mind. I think a question like yours - I have these requirements and I'd like the opinion of some people who know what they are doing - is just fine. I am a minority in that opinion. Many on this board, like the extension cord cut-up above, like to dismiss newbies they don't want to deal with and close their questions. Labeling something a shopping question is common tactic in this regard. My comment was pointing out what I see as an inconsistency as your question meets all the standards of questions they generally close. Best of luck.

Comment: @mikeY ah ok, i'm sorry i miss understood the first comment, to be honnest, when i asked the question i was a bit worried that some people won't like it, i've been using  stackexchange for a while and i know how some users think, but i had to ask it, i didn't get the answers i want elsewhere so i feel quite lucky that my question didn't get close and thankful for the user who answered me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LiPo batteries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_polymer_battery) are lightweight and have very high power density and output current. If cost is no object, they would probably be your best choice. However, be warned: if charged wrong or used improperly, they get angry. And [you won't like them when they're angry.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQheOtdCTjs).

They're also quite expensive, and require some fairly complex power electronics to reach maximum potential. If you're controlling a brushless DC motor, you can get neato off-the-shelf [ESCs](http://www.himodel.com/electric/HOBBYWING_150A_220A_2-6S_Electric_Brushless_Speed_Controller_ESC_Type_Platinum-150A-OPTO.html) which will let you drive them like a servo motor (with a PWM signal)... but BLDC motors tend to be much higher RPM than you'd want for a power scooter, so you'd have to gear it down.

Comment: thanks sir great choice that is, if it doesnt kill me :)